# WindowsServerにログインしたタイミングでパスワード変更が出来るようにしたいです。

Tags: linux, windows-server

サーバのパスワードの期限切れの対処方法についてお尋ねします。

Ｑ１：Windows Server 2016にログインするときにパスワードが期限切れでログイン出来ない場合、
　　「パスワード変更」へ誘導するような動きはできないでしょうか。

Ｑ２：Windows Server 2016にログインするときにパスワードが期限切れ間近の場合、
　　「期限切れまで〇〇日です。パスワードを変更しますか」というメッセージを表示し、
　　「パスワード変更」へ誘導するような動きはできないでしょうか。

Ｑ３：上記と同様な動きが、Linuxサーバでも出来ないでしょうか。

以上３点です。よろしくお願いいたします。